# Finding the buttons on the screen that have no text for the test

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, react-native-testing-library, react-native-ui-kitten

I am trying to write the tests for the NavBar component (using react-native-testing-library) that has several buttons that are basically just icons (using ui-kitten for react native). So I can't get these buttons by text (as there is none) but other methods didn't work for me either (like adding accesibilityLabel or testID and then getting by the label text / getting by test ID). Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```js
// NavBar.tsx
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {HomeBtn, SaveBtn} from '../components/buttons';
import UserSignOut from './UserSignOut';

const NavBar = ({
  navigation,
  pressHandlers,
}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.navBar}>
      <View>
        <HomeBtn navigation={navigation} />
        <SaveBtn pressHandler={pressHandlers?.saveBtn ?? undefined} />
      </View>
      <UserSignOut />
    </View>
  );
};
export default NavBar;

// HomeBtn.tsx
import React from 'react';
import {Button} from '@ui-kitten/components';
import {HomeIcon} from '../shared/icons';
import styles from './Btn.style';

export const HomeBtn = ({navigation}: any) => {
  return (
    <Button
      accesibilityLabel="home button"
      style={styles.button}
      accessoryLeft={props => HomeIcon(props, styles.icon)}
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
    />
  );
};

// NavBar.test.tsx
import React from 'react';
import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react-native';
import * as eva from '@eva-design/eva';
import {RootSiblingParent} from 'react-native-root-siblings';
import {EvaIconsPack} from '@ui-kitten/eva-icons';
import {ApplicationProvider, IconRegistry} from '@ui-kitten/components';
import NavBar from '../../containers/NavBar';

describe('NavBar', () => {
  const navBarContainer = (
    <RootSiblingParent>
      <IconRegistry icons={EvaIconsPack} />
      <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={eva.light}>
        <NavBar />
      </ApplicationProvider>
    </RootSiblingParent>
  );
  it('should render the buttons', async () => {
    render(navBarContainer);
    // this test fails (nothing is found with this accesibility label)
    await screen.findByLabelText('home button');
  });
});
```

Comment: screen.getByRole('button') finds no elements either =/

Comment: I never use react but can't you just select the button by attribute?

Comment: Don't know how I'd do it in React Native

Comment: I see the home button requires a propery named 'navigation' which is not provided in the test suite. In this way the button probably not rendered successfully. So the possible truth is that the button was not rendered and the test suite did work as expected(said that button wasn't render).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Query predicate

The recommended solution would be to use:

```
getByRole('button', { name: "home button" })
```

As it will require both the `button` role, as well as check `accessibilityLabel` with `name` option.

Alternative, but slightly less expressive way would be to use:

```
getByLabelText('home button')
```

This query will only check `accessibilityLabel` prop, which also should work fine.

#### Why is query not matching

Since you're asking why the query is not working, that depends on your test setup. It seems that you should be able to use sync `getBy*` query and do not need to await `findBy*` query, as the `HomeBtn` should be rendered without waiting for any async action.

What might prevent that test from working could be incorrect mocking of any of the wrapping components: `RootSiblingParent`, `ApplicationProvider`, they might be "consuming" `children` prop without rendering it. In order to diagnose the issue you can use `debug()` function from RNTL to inspect the current state of rendered components. You can also run your tests on `render(<NavBar />)` to verify that.

Answer (score 0):

Does `await screen.findByA11yLabel('home button')` work? It should match the `accessibilityLabel` prop.

Comment: await screen.findByLabelText('home button');   -  this doesn't find anything

Comment: `findByA11yLabel`, you're using `findByLabelText`

Comment: Property 'findByAllyLabel' does not exist on type '{ update: (component: ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>) => void;

Comment: My intellisense doesn't show this option on screen